# What is the best way when you want to send emails with using templates via WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, email, service

What is the best way when you want to send emails with using templates via WCF ?

This is not based on "programmer's personal feelings or tastes". I'm asking about which way is more powerfull and why ?( stability, performance, need less time - easy coding etc.)

My company want;
- Use razor engine( with custom implemention ) for editing email templates.
- Send it via other WCF email service.

I want;
- Use string builder for editing email templates.
- Send it via other WCF email service.

Or your third way ?

Answer (score 1):

Create an EmailTemplate table where you can store the EmailTemplates. Each email templates may have placeholders which you can replace in your code with values (ex : Customer Name, Address etc...) Create a UI ( an ASP.NET MVC web app) where you can edit each of this email template. All your edits will be saved to the EmailTemplate table. Write a WCF service which has a method to send an email. Nobody stops you from using StringBuilder if there are more number (i would say 5+ ) string concatinations.

Comment: My mentor stopped me :) He said; "if there is a nice coded library(razor engine), why are you using stringBuilder? Because you can make mistakes easly with stringBuilder..."